# Multiple bitrates/resolutions and creating HLS playlist issue

Tags: ffmpeg

When I run the command below, only the 1280x720 line works. The other two lines do not work. Where am I missing?

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -s:v:0 1280x720 -c:a aac -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 2000k \
-s:v:1 640x480  -c:a aac -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 1000k  \
-s:v:2 320x240 -c:a aac -c:v:2 libx264 -b:v:2 600k \
-f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -master_pl_name test.m3u8 \
-hls_segment_filename test_%v/test%06d.ts -use_localtime_mkdir 1 stream_%v.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the input video stream for each output video stream explicitly like this:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 \
-map 0:v:0 -s:v:0 1280x720 -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 2000k \
-map 0:v:0 -s:v:1 640x480  -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 1000k \
-map 0:v:0 -s:v:2 320x240  -c:v:2 libx264 -b:v:2 600k \
-c:a aac \
-f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -master_pl_name test.m3u8 \
-hls_segment_filename test_%v/test%06d.ts -use_localtime_mkdir 1 stream_%v.m3u8
```

Comment: Thanks, but i tried it, it has the same result. created only one m3u8

Comment: Oh, do you want to create separate files and not streams within a file?